# What does "+0800" in the command "stat" mean?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stat

```
stat -c "%y" *test.sh                                                                          
2015-08-25 10:35:44.711322327 +0800
2015-08-25 10:36:03.727295408 +0800
```

What does `+0800` mean? Sometimes it is `-0800`.

Comment: It's the time zone. You're 8 hours east of GMT.

Comment: Not in any way, shape or form specific to `stat` -- most RFC-specified date formats, when they have timezone support at all, express them that way.

Comment: And not a programming question, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the timezone. One's Pacifict Standard Time (-0800) and the other is China Standard Time (+0800). Check this out: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/